# how to validate return with input without using collective form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I try to use return ->withInput() but It didnt work here is my HTML and controller  Im using laravel 5.4 and in my form I'm using append to loop data too.

```
 <form action="{{route('subject.store')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">SUb</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject[]" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">credit</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="credit[]" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="add-me"></div>
    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
      <div class="offset-sm-3 col-sm-9">
        <button id="add-form" type="button" class="btn btn-default">addmore</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

and in my controller

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'subject.*' => 'required',
    'credit.*' => 'required',
],
[
    'subject.*.required' => 'The category name field is required.',
    'credit.*.required' => 'The sss name field is required.',

]

);

return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
```

My javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add-form').click(function() {
            i++;
            id_i++;                     
            $('#add-me').append(
                '<div class="form-group row">'
                +'<label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">sub</label>'
                +'<div class="col-sm-9">'
                +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject[]" placeholder="">'
                +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
                +'<div class="form-group row">'
                +'<label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">credit</label>'
                +'<div class="col-sm-9">'
                +'<input type="text" class="form-control" name="credit[]" placeholder="">'
                +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
                +'<hr>'
                );



        });
    });
```

when I submit data If have some validate how can I return back with old input

Answer (score 0):

Use `old` function to get it

Ex.

```
@if(count(old('subject', [])))
    @foreach(old('subject') as $subject)
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">SUb</label>
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text" value="{{ $subject }}" class="form-control" name="subject[]" placeholder="">
          </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label  class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">SUb</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject[]" placeholder="">
      </div>
    </div>
@endif
```